# A finite-$L_p$-norm measurable funtion that is a counterexample for an easy inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $(X,F,\mu)$ a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$, it is easy to show that, for every $u$ measurable, $$\limsup_{p \to \infty} ||u||_p \le ||u||_{\infty}$$

(it follows immediatly from the well-known inequality $||u||_p\le||u||_{\infty}\mu(X)^{1/p}$.) When $X$ has not finite measure it is easy to find a counterexample to the previuos inequality, for istance, when $X = \mathbb{R}$ dowed with the Lebesgue measure, we have $u_0\equiv 1$ and
$$
1=||u_0||_{\infty} < ||u_0||_p= + \infty.
$$
My question is: is it possibile to find a (infinite measure) measure space $X$ and a $u_0$ measurable such that
$$
||u_0||_{\infty} < \limsup_{p\to\infty}|u_0||_p <+ \infty ?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the original question:** Yes, how about: $X=\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure, and $u(x) = |x|^{-2/p}1_{\{|x|>1\}}$. So $\|u\|_\infty = 1$ and $\|u\|_p =2$.

**Answer to the edited question:** No, that is not possible. Assume $\limsup_{p\to\infty} \|u\|_p<\infty$ so that $\|u\|_p<\infty$ for some $p\ge 1$ which is fixed from now on. If $r>p$ then you always have $\|f\|_{r} \leq \|f\|_\infty^{1-\frac pr} \|f\|_p^{\frac pr}$. That follows from log convexity of Lp norms, see [Lemma 9 in these notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/). Letting $r\to\infty$ you get that $\limsup_{r\to\infty} \|f\|_r \leq \limsup_{r\to\infty}\|f\|_\infty^{1-\frac pr} \|f\|_p^{\frac pr} = \|f\|_\infty.$

Comment: Your answer is actually correct, but I failed at writing the question correctly. Now I edited it and the question is right, I'm sorry

Comment: I answered the edited question @StefanoSaviani